# TableViewCell not being displayed in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've come across a very strange issue suddenly in an app I'm building - the tableViewCells in my tableView are not showing up at all, even though the tableView methods are firing (I've checked using print statements within them). The app does not crash, but everything within the table view cell is just not showing up anymore, even though all data variables have been updated.

Below are the tableView methods I've used:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let count = selectedValidInputs.count
    return count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = carbonDetailsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CarbonDetailsCell") as! CarbonTableViewCell

    cell.itemName.text = selectedValidInputs[indexPath.row]
    cell.carbonValue.text = carbonValues[indexPath.row]
    cell.tip.text = tips[indexPath.row]
    cell.hashtag.text = tags[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Covering some questions that may be asked

1. I have a Controller that conforms to  UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, so override methods are not required
2. I have made sure the identifier for the CarbonTableViewCell (the custom UITableViewCell class) matches the one being used in .dequeueReusableCell method
3. I have verified all the variable connections from the storyboard to the code
4. I have not set the number of sections within the tableView, but the code had been working for a month without that too, so don't think the problem is associated with that.

I'm very new to coding altogether, so any help and feedback would be much appreciated!

Note that the page is just empty. Even the 'cellBg' variable below, which is just a view and has a background color, does not show up and neither does the app crash - which is a bit weird.

Edit: Since this is being suggested by everyone, just updating here. On printing the results, I get all values: When the input value is "apple" for example, all the values are shown:

```
count: 1
selectedValidInputs: ["apple (1 kg)"] 
carbonValues: ["550 g CO2, same as 22 plastic bags"] 
tips: ["Avoid wastage that adds unnecessary methane to the air with decomposition!"] 
tags: ["#very-low-carbon-impact"]
```

[When I add carbonDetailsTable.register(CarbonTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CarbonDetailsCell") to viewDidLoad(), I get a crash with the msg shown in attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy18C.png)

Comment: Have you debugged the code? print `count` in `numberOfRows`..

Comment: I do that and that also print the correct number. I printed all the data as well, which also shows the correct values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Try to implement also

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
 return 1
}
```

2) Try to implement also

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return 40.0
}
```

And comment the `estimatedRowHeight` and `rowHeight` setters, to confirm if the cell's autolayout is not broken and table view is unable to determine row height. 
(`estimatedRowHeight` is basically used just for tableView indicator bar and estimating the content size of tableView)

Comment: You were right about the table view not being able to determine the height. It seems the bottom constraint for the #hashtag label was deleted accidentally and that was the reason nothing was showing up. All other code being the same, the cell displays properly now, after adding a bottom spacing constraint. Feel like such an idiot!! Thank you so much for pointing me in this direction!

Answer (score 1):

Number of sections is equal 0, ‘selectedValidInputs’ array is empty or you have not placed all of the code that is initialising it with values.

Comment: I haven't placed the code that adds values to the array, but as updated above, upon printing in this ViewController all values are present. Also, if only the selectedValidInputs array was empty, it probably would result in the app crashing, which does not happen! The page is just empty. Even the 'cellBg' variable, which is just a view and a background, does not show up - that's a bit weird

Answer (score 0):

Print your Arrays which you are passing in tableview in CarbonDetailsViewController, and check data is exact as you passed in previous viewcontroller.

Comment: Yes, all data is present as mentioned in the post - I printed all values and rechecked!

Comment: what is your count in numberOfRows ? @kavyajha1004

Comment: The 'count' varies depending on the results - In the above example, it shows up as '1'

Comment: But strangely, the count gets printed thrice rather than once - don't know if that means anything

Comment: @kavyajha1004 where you writing  your print statement?

Comment: The 'count' is getting printed thrice when I use a print command in numberOfRowsInSection method. Then all the values get printed correctly (one time) in cellForRowAt indexPath: method. When I do print(cell.itemName.text!), even that prints the correct value!

Comment: Its not reflect on cell displaying on table. I didn't find any issues. @kavyajha1004

Comment: The issue turned out to be of table view not being able to estimate the row height, as pointed out by Lukas. Because the bottom spacing constraint for the '#hashtag' label was accidentally deleted, the entire cell wasn't displayed despite data being present. Thanks for taking time out to test this!